# CCLiquid renders my screen black

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d-iphone, latest non-beta version.

Recently I found this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:effects, and I was interested in CCLiquid or CCWaves for some water effects in my game.

However, when I apply CCLiquid action on my CCSprite, everything but the sprite itself is rendered black. Well, not exactly. When I increased the amplitude of the action, I noticed that it was actually a black background the size of the screen generated directly below my CCSprite (and such background was also being "waved").

Even though this is not a 3D action (no 3D suffix at least), I decided to follow the tip on that page and put this on my delegate:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDepthBufferFormat:kDepthBuffer16];
```

But `kDepthBuffer16` is not recognized anyway.

Any ideas?

*Edit*: Something that might be worth mentioning is that my sprite is being animated with CCAnimate.

Comment: i get the same effect with a plain vanilla sprite, no animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 1.0.1 , this fixed it for me (static image, no animation). This is in AppDelegate (in my case):

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    // Init the window

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] ) {
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];
    }

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller

    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Create the EAGLView manually

    EAGLView* glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];


    // attach the openglView to the director

    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

    // ... etc here  

}
```