# CCTurnOffTiles tints my CCSprites

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Cocos2d-iPhone version 1.0.1.

I am using `CCTurnOffTiles` action on a `CCSprite` (.png image, not animated).

**Sometimes**, everything goes smoothly. Other times, the sprite **seems to be tinted**. The tint color seems to be mostly **green**.

My AppDelegate has the settings I was suggested here: [CCLiquid renders my screen black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988260/ccliquid-renders-my-screen-black)

This is part of my original sprite:

[image]

And this is how it looks:

[image]

This is the action code:

```
id myAction = [[CCTurnOffTiles actionWithSize:ccg(35, 20) duration:0.7] reverse];
```

I use `reverse` because I want my tiles to turn ON rather than OFF. But I believe that the problem persists either way.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: I ended up making my own class for reproducing this type of animation. But still, I'd like to know what's going on here.

Comment: blendFunc perhaps in combination with glClearColor

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: By me? 'cuz I don't think I did any of those ever D: